# How do I subtract two columns with datetime in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am learning SQLite for work and I am trying to subtract 'Enddate' column fromn 'Startdate' column, which contain date and time. Soemthing like this:

```
Startdate  3/15/18 16:00  3/28/18 17:00

Enddate    3/19/18 00:00  3/20/18 00:00
```

My table's name is data1. I tried this:

```
select *,
    strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M', 'data1.Enddate') -
        (strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M', 'data1.Startdate')) as TimeOff
from data1;
```

But this gives me all 'Null' values.

If you could help me with this I would really appreciate that. That you so much!

Comment: Your current date format of `%m/%d/%y` is going to make this very difficult.  Please consider getting your dates into a year-month-day format.  Once you have done that, you can easily use `julianday` to get a difference between two timestamps.

Comment: Which version of SQL? And what does `strftime()` do? What datatype does it return? Can you just do `date1.Enddate - date1.Startdate` and then apply the formatting to the returned value? Do `EndDate` and `StartDate` return values before you try to format them?

Comment: SQLite supports [a limited number of date/time string formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), and your dates and times don't conform to any of them. If you want to do any sort of manipulation of those dates and times within SQLite, you'll either need to change how they're inserted or do some complicated string manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible reasons you got `NULL` (likely because of a silent error):
1) Your dates are malformed when you create them. They should be `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format instead. 
2) Not having a closing semicolon in one of your queries. I see it in the one above, but if the one where you insert your test rows didn't close properly, you may not

My test query:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=8b9a168291bbc08c74a895ce22ab41ac

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE data1 (foo int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime) ;

INSERT INTO data1 (foo, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES (1,'2018-03-15 16:00:00', '2018-03-28 17:00:00') 
  , (2,'2018-03-19 00:00:00', '2018-03-20 00:00:00') ;
```

**The Query**

```
SELECT foo, StartDate, EndDate
   , julianday(EndDate)-julianday(StartDate) AS TimeOffInDays
   , CAST((julianday(EndDate) - julianday(StartDate))*24 AS real) AS TimeOffInHours
FROM data1 ;
```

**Which gives us...**

```
|  foo  |     StartDate       |       EndDate       |  TimeOffInDays  | TimeOffInHours  |
=========================================================================================  
|   1   | 2018-03-15 16:00:00 | 2018-03-28 17:00:00 | 13.041666666977 | 313.00000000745 |
|   2   | 2018-03-19 00:00:00 | 2018-03-20 00:00:00 |        1        |       24        |
```

Comment: Try this and see that it doesn't work: `select DATETIME('now') - DATETIME('now', '-20 days');` it always return `0`